# Move data from one prestashop version to another

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, data-extraction, data-export

I have a client website that is running on Prestashop v1.4

Because it has been "maintained" by a previous developer who modified core files and generally made a big mess, the upgrade module no longer works properly. Given that the client is handing over the project to me, and wants a new theme implemented, I am moving straight to Prestashop 1.6 and using the Compass/Boostrap 3 default theme as a base.

Obviously, the important thing is that the clients data should be migrated. So my question is, is it possible to make a clean export from Prestashop 1.4 of only the actual sales and website access data, skipping anything like module configs etc, in order to reimport it all to Prestashop 1.6?

This way, my client can keep his order data, access data, products, payments etc, and I can build a new theme without having to fight with an old installation or theme that have hardcoded rubbish in it.

Comment: Have you compared the db schema differences between the two versions? A "manual" or command line export/import could work for data in some tables if their schema is not so different.

Comment: Plus, there seem to be some free import/export modules (XML, CSV). http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/266121-module-from-prestashop-to-prestashop-products-import-products-export-in-xml-or-csv-free/

Comment: Yup, but that one only exports products. I simply need to know how to massage the data back in. There seem to be a lot of differences in the DB formats. There is an export all module, but it is very expensive.

Comment: What about my first question?? You can use the free MySQL Workbench to see differences or synchronise schemas on different servers.

Comment: Using mysqldiff gives me a lot of differences.

Comment: The DB schema is very different, and during the upgrade not only SQL code is executed, but PHP code that makes changes to the DB based on the specific configuration. May be it's a better idea to fix the mess that previous developer has created on 1.4, and then try again to upgrade. If something fails during the upgrade, fix the original DB and try again. Save all the queries and apply them one by one until the upgrade goes well.

Comment: I took your advice, and tried the 1-click upgrade module again. It appears that it works better than last time, as there was only one SQL problem (ps_order_tax table missing) which is quite reassuring.

Comment: It is possible to migrate data (categories, products, customers and orders) exporting them from old instance and importing to new PrestaShop store with free 2 week version of Presta Store Manager extension. Here is step-by-step guide - https://www.prestashopmanager.com/useful-articles/how-to/how-to-transfer-prestashop-database-to-another-store/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **[module](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/8934-prestashop-to-prestashop-migration-tool.html)** provides an automated method migrate products, customers, orders, categories, customers password and other data from Prestashop to Prestashop.

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/8934-prestashop-to-prestashop-migration-tool.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose many migrate module to do your request.

If you only want to upgrade the current site to 1.6 (or the latest version). you can create a new site and transfer all of the data from the current site to the live site.
After you had set up the live site completely, you just re-transfer data from the new site to the live site. you can use a module many times with the site that has been granted a license.

If you want to transfer Product, categories and customer, you just use the [Upgrade PrestaShop 1.6 to 1.7 free](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/)

If you want to transfer all of the data (products, customer, categories, order, cms, message, shipping,...) you should purchase the premium version module: [1 CLICK to migrate](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/31424-1-click-to-migrate-or-upgrade.html)